# in Javafx: for the x-axis, how to turn epoch time into a date label on the ticks?

Tags: java, javafx, axis

I'm trying to map data to time on JavaFX in a graph that keeps getting new info added.

The problem is not being able to show dates on the x-axis in a line graph in JavaFX.

So I am trying to use the epoch values to represent the dates (which works) and then convert the relevant ticks on the graph to dates using `setTickLabelFormatter` to make it easier to read (which doesn't work very well).

Here's my code:

```
xAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(xAxis)
{
    @Override
    public String toString(Number object)
    {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy");

        System.out.println("converting time for graph " + object);

        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(object.longValue()), ZoneId.systemDefault());

        String formattedDateTime = dateTime.format(formatter);

        System.out.println("populating graph with date " + formattedDateTime);
        return formattedDateTime;
    }
});
```

The output I get is for the `System.out.println` is:

```
converting time for graph 0.0  
populating graph with date 01-Jan-1970  
converting time for graph 1.0E8  
populating graph with date 02-Jan-1970  
converting time for graph 2.0E8  
populating graph with date 03-Jan-1970  
converting time for graph 3.0E8  
populating graph with date 04-Jan-1970  
converting time for graph 4.0E8  
populating graph with date 06-Jan-1970  
converting time for graph 5.0E8  
populating graph with date 07-Jan-1970  
converting time for graph 6.0E8  
populating graph with date 08-Jan-1970  
converting time for graph 7.0E8  
populating graph with date 09-Jan-1970  
converting time for graph 8.0E8  
populating graph with date 10-Jan-1970  
converting time for graph 9.0E8  
populating graph with date 11-Jan-1970  
converting time for graph 1.0E9  
populating graph with date 13-Jan-1970  
converting time for graph 1.1E9  
populating graph with date 14-Jan-1970  
converting time for graph 1.2E9  
populating graph with date 15-Jan-1970  
converting time for graph 1.3E9  
populating graph with date 16-Jan-1970  
converting time for graph 1.4E9  
populating graph with date 17-Jan-1970  
converting time for graph 1.5E9  
populating graph with date 18-Jan-1970  
converting time for graph 1.6E9  
populating graph with date 20-Jan-1970  
...
```

Where am I going wrong and how could I convert the date in seconds since the epoch into a more human readable date?

Comment: What is the output you expect / want to see?

Comment: I want to have the date as a human readable format for each tick on the graphs x-axis. For example, 30 Sep 2017. But the calculation isn't giving me the right answer - rather it is returning variations on 01 Jan 1970 even though the data in epoch second format is correct.